# How to dynamically pass in data to search with jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to render some data.  Now I want the ability to modify the data based on the values of two different select boxes.  For example, I have a dropdown of location id's and a dropdown of date ranges.  I want to filter by the location id and date range, handling this logic in my `/something/search` action.  How can I pass this additional data into jqGrid dynamically?  So, (1) on the initial load and (2) when on onChange event is fired, i'll pass in something like `{data: {location_id: 10, range_start: '1/1/2012', range_end: '1/5/2010'}}`.  I could then read this in as a param, just like I do for `"page", "rows", "sidx"`, etc..

Edit:
Included my existing code if needed:

```
grid.jqGrid({
  url: "/something/search",
  datatype: "json",
  colNames: ['', 'ID', 'Description', 'Start', 'End', 'Last Updated'],
  colModel: [{name:'act',index:'act', width:16,sortable:false},
             { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 100, hidden: true },
             { name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 200 },
             { name: 'start_date', index: 'start_date', width: 120 },
             { name: 'end_date', index: 'end_date', width: 120 },
             { name: 'last_update', index: 'last_update', width: 120 }],
  rowNum: 20,
  rowList: [10, 20, 50],
  pager: '#data-list-pager',
  sortname: 'ident',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
  multiselect: false,
  height: "100%",
  caption: "",
  altRows: true,
  width: 865});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way to solve the problem is to follow the way which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935). In the case the controls which the user will use to filter the grid will be outside of the grid.

Another way which I can suggest is to use the [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). The advantage of the approach is that the controls used for searching will be *integrated* in the grid. In the case you can use either the select control or text input with the jQuery UI Datepicker.

To add the [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) you need just call `filterToolbar` with the parameters which you prefer. If you would you stringResult: true option the format of the `filters` parameter which will be send to the server will be [the same](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) like in case of the usage of advanced searching. To define 'greater or equal' searching operation for the `'start_date'` and the 'less or equal' searching operation for the `'end_date'` you need just add `searchoptions` having `'ge'` or `'le'` as the first element of the `sopt` property.

As the result one will be able to filter the grid:

[image]

and

[image]

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchForDateInterval.htm).

Comment: Thanks.  The data I have will not be returned in the jqGrid, but I will take a look at postData.